# making LSH implementation faster in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, minhash, lsh

I am implementing minhash and LSH for similarity search for some string elements in C++11. The minhash sketch for my implementation is a vector of 200 64-bit integers i.e. `vector<uint64_t> MinHashSketch`. I have more than 2 million entries and the sketch generation portion does not take much time. But, the bucketing stage takes a long time. I am wondering if I can get some suggestions to make it a bit faster. Following is my bucketing stage using LSH.

I am taking consecutive elements in the sketch to create a hash which becomes bucket id. If `bsize = 5`, then `1-5, 6-10, 11-15, ... 196-200` elements in `MinHashSketch[i]` (for ith element) forms the bucket ids. Following the piece of code that does that.

```
for (int p = 0; p < 200; p += bsize) {  //bsize = 5
  string s = ""; 
  for(int x = p; x < (p+bsize); x++){
    s = s + to_string(MinHashSketch[i].at(x)); // ith element 
  }       
  uint64_t hash1 = 0;  // bucket id
  Hash_function ((uint8_t*)s.c_str(), s.length(), (uint8_t *)&hash1, 0);
  ........
  ........
}
```

Comment: What type is `MinHashSketch`? If it's `vector<uint64_t>` the expression `MinHashSketch[i].at(x)` is illformed. This looks like a vector of vectors?

Comment: Do you really need to convert your numbers to strings? Can't you just hash raw bytes? As in `Hash_function(&MinHashSketch[i][p], sizeof(uint64_t)*bsize, ...)` and drop the inner loop.

Comment: @Timo Yes, it is a vector of vectors. For every element, it is a vector of 200 64-bit integers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks!! I will try that. I was doing it differently, bt had some syntax error.

Comment: The second parameter of hash function is `long unsigned int`. This is the error `error: no matching function for call to ‘MetroHash64::Hash(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<long unsigned int> >::value_type*, long unsigned int, uint8_t*, int)’`

Comment: Cast the first parameter to `uint8_t*`, same as you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik !! It worked fine now. It did improve a little bit. It seems I need to work on the other parts of the code.